# Node.js / v8 assignment operator overloading

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, node-modules, embedded-v8

My question is simple, How do you define the behavior of assignment operator in v8 / Node.js?

Assume I have a class in C++ domain that have a `set` method. Normally when I write this JS:

```
var jsInstance = new CppWrappedClass(params1);
jsInstance = new CppWrappedClass(params2);
```

The second call to `new CppWrappedClass(...)` totally replaces the contents of `jsInstance` with the new one. What I would want to achieve is that when the second call happens, in its C++ backend, my `set` method gets called. Aka I define the behavior of assignment operator.

Is this even possible?

Comment: no, it's not possible

Comment: ECMAscript (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13) says there should be a function called `PutValue` but I am assuming that is not overridable, because I don't see it in Chrome's dev console.